# How to prolong a progress bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, progress-bar

I would like to know how to prolong a progress bar after it's over?

Let me explain :

My progressbar starts at a specific time (now) and ends for example in 10 minutes ( its like now = 0% and 10min = 100%). After the 10 min, I would like to extend mat progress bar if there is delay (i am doing this because I would like with a progress bar that starts when a person has started a task, and the number of minutes he has to do on that task, if he has not finished at 10 minutes, my progress bar is going down and continue until the moment he finishes, and the delay par will be in other color ).

I did that in my code: (ps : i did this code for the test: its not really this one I have in my project because in my real code I use BDD and plenty other things)

[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-kowalevski-dukr7)

So , I just want to prolong my progress bar but don't know how to make it, I tried "Stacked Progress Bars " from here [Stacked Progress Bars](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp) but it's not the real result I want

Comment: Could you just un-mount and then re-mount the ProgressBar component at the end of 10 minutes? Basically just re-start itself as is. That's probably easiest without refactoring what you've already got.

Comment: In the link i added on the « app.js » if you add your current time (like = new Date() and the moment you when he start) you will see the progress bar start and stop avec few second (the 10min its was just for the exemple). So what you want to say for « re-start itself ? Ps: I am not an English speaker

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre]. Code relevant to your problem needs to be included in the question itself (in text form and properly formatted, or directly as a stack snippet in cases where that makes sense), and not just dumped onto an external platform.